# Changing colors of next iteration using arrays java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, processing

I'm trying to get the next iteration of a repetition to change color, using arrays (and also worth noting that I'm using the processing library) and it does not seem to work out, I've tried moving the "if's" into the setup, inside the "for" outside the "for" inside the "draw" but the colors just seem to flicker, here is what I'm trying to achieve:
it is necessary to use the for function.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEwuI.png)

```
public void settings() {
    size(500, 500);
}

int estado;
int[] cuadrados;

@Override
public void setup() {
    
    cuadrados = new int[8];

    /*
     * cuadrados[0]=(estado=0); cuadrados[1]=(estado=1); cuadrados[2]=(estado=2);
     * cuadrados[3]=(estado=3); cuadrados[4]=(estado=4); cuadrados[5]=(estado=5);
     */

    println(estado);
    println(cuadrados);
}

@Override
public void draw() {
    
    
    background(255);
    if (estado == 0) {
        fill(255, 255, 0);
    }
    if (estado == 1) {
        fill(0, 0, 255);
    }
    if (estado == 2) {
        fill(255, 0, 0);
    }
    if (estado == 3) {
        fill(255);
    }
    if (estado == 4) {
        fill(255);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

        cuadrados[i] = estado;

        rect(4 + (i * 62), 200, 55, 55);
        estado += 1;
        if (estado > 4) {
            estado = 0;
        }

    }

}
```

}

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure with my answer, But you can try this, I think it works.

```
while(i<8)
{   switch(estado)
   {
    case 1:
    fill(255,0,0);
    break;
    case 2:
    fill(0,255,0)
    break;
    default:
    draw(); or i = 1;// try using both, Either u set the value to 1 again. or you call 
                     //that function again and again 
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be new to Processing. You cannot guess just like that, but in Processing the `draw()` method is a loop which will run automatically about 60 times per second. It's akin to the "main loop" of a game. You got the right idea: changing color then drawing, but you did it java style, which wouldn't work as intended in this context.

Comment: alright buddy, I never used it thats true, So i guessed. Thank you for the feedback

Comment: If by any chance you happen to be a very motivated student, I strongly suggest that you take an interest in 'The Nature of Code' by Daniel Shiffman. You can read it online for free. It uses Processing to teach hands-on about several very interesting mechanics, particularly if you want to code games.

Answer (score 0):

The `draw()` loop iterate about 60 times per second, that's why the colors flicker like madness itself: you're re-drawing them that often. Also, you're picking 1 color and then drawing all your squares... if you could pause the flickering squares, you would see that they are the same color. So there's 2 things to fix here:

1. Stopping the `draw` loop after you have your colors (either stopping the loop or making sure that the colors won't change at every iteration of the loop).
2. Making sure that you change color inside the `for` loop, so every new square has it's own color.

We can in fact ditch the draw() loop completely if you're just drawing those squares (and work in the `setup` method), or use `noLoop()` after the squares has been drawn. Or you can make sure that every square will always get the same color when they are drawn - which you're already doing, in a way, since `estado` will always reset the same way at every iteration of the `draw()` loop, but let's reset it manually anyway just in case you change the number of squares or colors later.

There's many, many ways to fix the second point. I like to isolate small logic like that inside helper methods, so I've moved your "color select" code inside a function that you can call at the right moment in the `for` loop where you draw the squares, the right moment for changing color being "before you draw the square".

Here's the modified code:

```
int estado;
int[] cuadrados;

public void settings() {
  size(500, 500);
}

public void setup() {
  cuadrados = new int[8];

  println(estado);
  println(cuadrados);
}

public void draw() {
  background(255);

  estado = 0; // reseting estado so the colors stays in the same order

  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    cuadrados[i] = estado;

    fill(getColor(estado)); //changing the color before we draw a new square
    rect(4 + (i * 62), 200, 55, 55);

    estado += 1;
    if (estado > 4) {
      estado = 0;
    }
  }
}

color getColor(int index) {
  // I'm using a switch because I like switches for this kind of use, but your code would have worked too. It's less efficient, though, hence the switch.
  switch (index) {
  case 0:
    return color(255, 255, 0);
    // Careful here! This switch doesn't need `break;` statements because it makes returns instead, but in any other case I would have needed them!
  case 1:
    return color(0, 0, 255);
  case 2:
    return color(255, 0, 0);
  case 3:
    return color(255);
  case 4:
    return color(255);
  }

  return color(0); // if you get a black square, you know there's something wrong
}
```

I'll stick around, if you have questions I'll try to help further.

Have fun!